# Should I ask a new question about the same error in different context?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I have the same error as described in a relatively old, but not answered question: [Spyder's Warning: "Session/line number not unique in database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986087/spyders-warning-session-line-number-not-unique-in-database)

While the context of the error is different (I get it in Jupyter notebook), I suspect they share the same cause. Literally the same piece of software used by both Jupyter and Spyder.

I have a feeling that it is a new question, but I am afraid such question may be closed as a duplicate (as there is the same error, and probably its cause and answer).

Comment: It appears that error is intermittent. Better to open an issue with Spyder (GitHub?)

Comment: A question can't be closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question by a different user (well, I think mods might be able to, but the rest of us can't). Interpret that as you wish.

Answer (score -1):

> I have the same error
>   I suspect they share the same cause

This makes it seem very much like it would be the same question. Which if so  would make a new one a duplicate. The current one having no answers doesn't stop it being a duplicate.

And you have to ask why would making a new one gain any answers if another one (older or not) has not? The main reasons are:

1. The question is not so clear or not well written - therefore edit the current one to improve it
2. It's 2 years old now and might not gain fresh attention - then add a bounty

> While the context of the error is different

This doesn't make it a different question, unless the context alters the potential cause of the issue. But deciding that is unfortunately hard without knowing the cause.

> I have a feeling that it is a new question

Given the reasons you gave that it's going to be the same issue and cause, what do you think makes it a different question?

---

I suggest you place a bounty and see what comes of it. Bounty questions usually do well. Then you may either get an answer to your issue too, or perhaps at least answers will show that the issue you face warrants a new question.

Comment: "The current one having no answers doesn't stop it being a duplicate". No but it does stop it being closed as a duplicate on SO using the original question as the question duplicated.

Comment: "This makes it seem very much like it would be the same question" - assumption is the mother of all f***ups. Just because it seems like it has the same cause doesn't mean it really does.

Comment: Which is why I put "makes it seem" rather than "this is definitely I'm sure 100%" ;) It was general advice, without any presumptions just suggesting at a possibility. What else are you going to do? Wait and see? The old question is dead, so bounty it. Or add a new question and see if you get answers then post a comment on the old one asking "does this resolve your issue".

Comment: The question is different. I have succesfully reproduced the error in Jupyter but not in Spyder.

Comment: no probs, I went by your question here "*I suspect they share the same cause. Literally the same piece of software used by both Jupyter and Spyder.*"